# helm template values and set variables

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have this section in my service template. I want, if variable publicIP is defined, define loadBalancerIP.

```
  {{- if .Values.publicIP }}
  loadBalancerIP: {{ .Values.publicIP }}
  {{- end }}
```

in my values.$environment.yml

I define

publicIP: null

And I need to define publicIP when I do helm install, for example:

```
helm install release release/path -f values.$environment.yml  -—set publicIP=127.0.0.1
```

But it isn't working. What can I do to define publicIP and it defines in my template?

Comment: Does it take public ip as null ? Or blank? Also try --debug --dry-run to check if publicIP is getting passed as 127.0.0.1

Comment: Does 'helm template` with the same `-f` and `--set` options include the value?  That template code seems correct.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand the question but if you want to set an individual parameter you need to do it with

> "--set"

eg : `helm install --set foo=bar ./mychart`

---

What is the name of your values.yml? values.$environment.yml?
Try also command like this

```
helm install release release/path -f --values {YOUR_VALUES_FILE}.yml  --set publicIP=127.0.0.1
```

and be sure to use --, you seem in the example provided to use a weird special character much longer than a normal dash.

And second is **publicIP** a root parameter?
if you  have something like this in {YOUR_VALUES_FILE}.yml

```
root
  node: null
```

you need to set it like this :

```
helm install release release/path -f --values {YOUR_VALUES_FILE}.yml  --set root.node=value
```

Comment: It is my mistake in "--set" in the question, yes I try to set variable, but it is not define